# post a new form after updating innerhtml

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two forms on my page and I am submitting one of them via ajax, then updating the innerHTML on success:

```
 $(document).on('change','input[name=datavalue]',function() {
  var datavalue = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'pra.php',
    data: { datavalue: datavalue },
    success: function(response) {
  
      document.getElementById("returnvalue").innerHTML=response;
      // handle success response
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log('AJAX request error:');
      console.log('Status:', status);
      console.log('Error:', error);
    }
  });
});
```

But the problem is after updating my html page, I cannot submit my other form.

```
 <form id="form" class=""  action="" method="post">
<textarea  name="workDone" rows="2" cols="50"></textarea>
<button 
 type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="add" >ADD</button>
</form>
```

I understand the logic behind it (a little) but couldn't find a way to fix this. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Changed the second form post to delegate function ajax (removed `type="submit"`) but data is undefined on the console.log

```
$(document).on('click','[name=add]',function() {
 var workDone = $(workDone).val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'pra.php',
        data: { workDone: workDone },
        success: function(response) {
      
          document.getElementById("returnvalue").innerHTML=response;
          // handle success response
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log('AJAX request error:');
          console.log('Status:', status);
          console.log('Error:', error);
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Why can't you submit the other form? What happens when you try?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a delegated event handler as you are creating the new form after the page first loads.

Comment: I am clicking the button but nothing happens @Barmar

Comment: You have no `action` URL in the form. Does the web page contain a server-side script to process it?

Comment: both side are on the same page and button works if I don't trigger the ajax @barmar

Comment: then I need another ajax right? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Probably need to show all the code.... Your form might be invalid, your innerHTML changing might be messing it up. Hard to guess.

Comment: Does the Network tab in DevTools show the form being submitted?

Comment: @Barmar I don't know how to check that but print_r($_POST); returns empty after ajax

Comment: ajax form is working fine and other form is working fine before ajax, I am not sure which parts should I share since there is so much code.Response returns the html of the page with just an updated span (I echoed datavalue inside ). @epascarello

Comment: the `ADD` button doesn't have a value, what do you expect `$(this).val()` to be in the new code?

Comment: Where do you set `workDone`?

Comment: You need to use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the submit button from submitting the form and reloading the page. Or change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`.

Comment: @barmar sorry,edited but still the same

Comment: `var workDone = $("[name=workDone]").val()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253557/discussion-between-wittream-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to your suggestions, it is fixed:

```
$(document).on('click','[name=add]',function() {
 var workDone = $('[name=workDone]').val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'pra.php',
        data: { workDone: workDone },
        success: function(response) {
      
          document.getElementById("returnvalue").innerHTML=response;
          // handle success response
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log('AJAX request error:');
          console.log('Status:', status);
          console.log('Error:', error);
        }
      });
    });
```